# How to search Google for other domains than `.com`?

Tags: google-search

I wanted to fire up a search query on Google on other than .com domains.

I understand that providing `site:.org` will result all the search actions on specifically `org` domains but is there a `not` operator?

Comment: How about `-site:.com *`?

Comment: @onewhaleid, this is, in fact, the answer. Just put it as an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-` operator, e.g.

`youtube -site:.com` will exclude:

[youtube.com](http://youtube.com)

You can add the `*` operator to remove other domains, e.g.

`youtube -site:.com *` will exclude:

[youtube.com.au](http://youtube.com.au)

[youtube.com.hk](http://youtube.com.hk)

[youtube.com.sg](http://youtube.com.sg)